# Linking script.js and html5

Tags: jquery, html, web

So Ive been going through some of the codeacademy stuff on HTML/CSS and Jquery.

Having a bit of trouble trying to get my code to work outside on my local machine.

Here is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Krypton Redux</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css'/>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>    </head>

    <body>

        <div></div>
        <div style = "margin:10"></div>
        <div></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

here is my jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div').draggable();
});
```

When I write the jQuery code directly in my HTML file then open it in Chrome, it works.
However when doing it in a .js file I get an error saying that '$' is not recognized. Anyone have any idea why?

Comment: Are you including your JS file before or after the jQuery library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$` is the jQuery alias. If you are using the `$` in your script, jQuery must be defined before your script. It's a simple fix. Rearrange your script links like so:

```
<!-- Load jQuery first -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<!-- Since you use jQuery UI in your script as well, load it second. -->
<!-- Note however that jQuery Core must be included before UI because it's a dependency -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<!-- Finally, load your script -->
<script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks alot. That was a pretty careless mistake. 
I assumed that the HTML file would load everything first before any script is exceuted

Comment: @RobertLemiesz Haha. No worries buddy. It happens to the best of it. My understanding, and I still could be wrong on this, as that each script file is parsed fully right after it's downloaded before continuing on to the next. [This](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/) site has a lot of "best practices" tips.

Answer (score 3):

Add the `script.js` below the `jQuery` script.

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css'/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
```